# IntentService null pointer exception using this

Tags: android, intentservice, android-context

I'm using the following intent service to handle GCM messages, it's working perfectly almost all time except for very few times where it throws a null pointer exception for what it seems to be a null context as shown by the code surrounded by stars, should I using something else other than the "this"? if yes then what should I use?

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    NetworkThread thread;
    static final String TAG = "IntentService";

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
        thread = new NetworkThread();
        thread.start();
        thread.getLooper();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        if (!extras.isEmpty()) { 

            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR 
                    .equals(messageType)) {

            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {



            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {

                  if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("NEW_MESSAGE")) {
                    ***********************************
                    thread.handleMessage(new JsonObj(extras.getString("message"), this ));
                    ***********************************
                }
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

The thread handler code is below,

```
public class NetworkThread extends HandlerThread {

    public void handleMessage(JsonObj jObj) {

        mHandler.obtainMessage(HANDLE_MESSAGE, jObj)//this is line 153
                .sendToTarget();

    }




    protected void onLooperPrepared() {
    mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                //here I handle different kinds of messages
        case HANDLE_MESSAGE:

        break;
        }

    }

}
```

The error is below

```
10-13 22:08:41.159: E/AndroidRuntime(18279): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GcmIntentService]
10-13 22:08:41.159: E/AndroidRuntime(18279): Process: com.messaging.android, PID: 18279
10-13 22:08:41.159: E/AndroidRuntime(18279): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-13 22:08:41.159: E/AndroidRuntime(18279):    at com.messaging.android.NetworkThread.handleMessage(NetworkThread.java:153)
10-13 22:08:41.159: E/AndroidRuntime(18279):    at com.messaging.android.GcmIntentService.onHandleIntent(GcmIntentService.java:106)
10-13 22:08:41.159: E/AndroidRuntime(18279):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
10-13 22:08:41.159: E/AndroidRuntime(18279):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-13 22:08:41.159: E/AndroidRuntime(18279):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-13 22:08:41.159: E/AndroidRuntime(18279):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: The IntentService is probably getting killed by the time your other thread is done. you are already in a separate thread so you shoudnt need to create a new one anyway

Comment: What happens in `NetworkThread.handleMessage()` (specifically line 153)?

Comment: I'm extending HandlerThread, I'll update the code with it